# How to make clipboard sync between Windows 10 Mobile & PC on UWP C# app?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I know that there is `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings`, but it doesn't work and beahves like `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings`. The "RoamingSettings" saves data locally, and never syncing between Mobile and PC or opposide, maybe because version difference, my Phone is running version 1507, while PC - 2010 (20H2) version. The Microsoft Account is the same in both devices. So how I can synchronize the clipboard between PC and Phone? Is there other APIs that allowing to sync data on UWP?

So, here is a simple function using "RoamingSettings".

```
    static ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings =
        ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
    public static void SendText(string text)
    {
        if (!roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("clipboardText"))
        {
            roamingSettings.Values.Add("clipboardText", text);
        }
        else
        {
            roamingSettings.Values["clipboardText"] = text;
        }
    }

    public static string ReceiveText
    {
        get
        {
            if (roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("clipboardText"))
            {
                string text = roamingSettings.Values["clipboardText"].ToString();
                return text;
            }

            return "";
        }
    }
```

**Update**

The `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingStorageQuota` returns 0 on PC, but on Mobile it returns 100 as normally.

**Update 2**

`RoamingSettings` has been discontinued since version 2004, see [Windows 10 features we’re no longer developing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-deprecated-features). That's the reason why `RoamingStorageQuota` returns 0 instead of 100. So I've tested the app on Windows 10 1507 and it returns 100 and syncs the data, but after reinstalling the app on Mobile. However it's working on older versions.

The question is that is it possible to bring Package State Roaming (PSR) back to version 2004 or above? If no, are there alternatives for PSR?

Comment: Are the versions of the packages you installed on phone and PC the same? App data only roams between installed apps with the same version number. Please check the limitation of roaming data here:[Roaming data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#roaming-data)

Comment: The version of app is a same. I've debuged the app from same project on Visual Studio 2017. I know the limitation, but I think it should've transfer one or few words.

Comment: Does the [ApplicationData.DataChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.datachanged?view=winrt-19041) fire?

Comment: No, it doesn't fire.

Comment: A possible reason is that you are using the full size of the roaming data in your PC so none of the app's app data will be replicated to the cloud.

Comment: I think no, 'cause I've tested RoamingStorageQuota on blank app with absolutely no code, and it still return 0. I've cleared RoamingSettings values but no result. Microsoft account is the same, the sync is turned on, OneDrive works properly. I think that it comes from PC, but what exactly happening?

Comment: Do you have another PC to test the storage size?  It might be better if we could confirm whether this is a question related to a specific device.

Comment: I would test this app on VirtualBox using VS's Remote Machine feature.

Comment: I've tested the app on older version, and it works. See the "Update 2" section.

Comment: No, currently, there is available information about bringing PSR back. This feature is removed.